# Finding the cause of a TypeError using Sqlalchemy in Python 3 to insert into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, python-3.5

I have migrated a working database from SQLite3 to MySQL.  Most of it works well, but on one table I get the following error when trying to add a row:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pymysql.err.Error) (<class 'TypeError'>, TypeError("a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'",)) [SQL: 'INSERT INTO offers2 (`OfferID`) VALUES (%s)'] [parameters: (999999,)]
```

I tried turing on echo to see what it's doing and this is where it fails:

```
2017-10-06 20:24:34,453 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2017-10-06 20:24:34,454 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO offers2 (`OfferID`) VALUES (%s)
2017-10-06 20:24:34,454 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (999999,)
2017-10-06 20:24:34,455 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
```

The OfferID is defined as such in Python:

```
class Offers(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'offers2'
    OfferID = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
```

The MySQL table schema is:

```
-- auto-generated definition
CREATE TABLE offers2
(
  OfferID INT AUTO_INCREMENT
    PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Can anyone help me understand the problem and how to trace it?

The offers table contained many more columns, but I tried pairing it back to only the primary key to see if I could isolate the issue, but still it remains.

Comment: What happens when you explicitly insert values for other columns in the table but let the OfferID primary key automatically increment? Is your intent to indeed use an externally generated value for the primary key?

Comment: Don, the original query didn't explicitly enter a value for the OfferID - it was set to autoincrement, and it still generated the same issue.  Something I should have mentioned; if I turn on echo to view the query, and take the query string I can get it to insert correctly if I copy it to the console and run it, but I have to change None values to Null.  With this in mind I tried inserting the records ensuring there were no nulls and the error still appears, making me think it may be an issue with pymysql or sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who stumble across this question by searching for the same error output:

After some experimentation I found that if I turned on echo to see the query, then took the SQL insert string and tried applying it in the mySQL console the code would work.

This led me to the conclusion that the issue must lie either in SQLAlchemy or the pymysql connection I was using, so I tried changing from pymysql to mySQLdb and found the query worked as expected, and as it had worked previously when I had the database in SQLite3.